# Questionnaire data in linear mixed-effects model -> fixed effect?

Tags: mixed-model

I want to build a linear mixed-effects model.

Condition was changed within subjects, so as fixed effect, I entered condition and as random effects subjects, items and a by-subject random slope for condition.

In a second step, I wanted to include scores of a questionnaire that were collected from participants before the experiment and are believed to influence the dependent variable as well.

Thus, is this a fixed or a random effect?

Comment: Is there just one or one for each item? Do you mean item by pre-experiment value (influence presumably differs by item?)? Subject by condition may be unusual, but perhaps not in your field.

Comment: @Björn There is one questionnaire score for each subject (indicating how stressed they were before the experiment).